# store variable value to the user disconnection

Tags: php, symfony, session-variables

I would like to send the contents of a variable from one page to another. The variable is entered by the user.

```
$session =$this->get('request')->getSession();
$typeRapport = $session->get('typeRapport');
```

Comment: @Sgoettschkes - It's probably advisable to form complete, coherent sentences and spell "grammar" correctly when insulting another's use of it; that's just my 2 cents.

Comment: @user91599 it's really hard to read your question. You'll need to rephrase it to get an answer. Some commas and periods would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you did everything! You question is: "I would like to send the contents of a variable from one page to another".

If you are capable to get the Session object, why don't you set a param in it?
E.g.

Controller of first page:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

public function firstPageAction(Request $request){
  $myValue = ....; // value to be passed
  $session = $request->getSession();
  $session->set('typeRapport', $myValue);    
...
}
```

Then, in the controller of the second page:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

...

public function secondPageAction(Request request){
  $session = $request->getSession();
  $typeRapport = $session->get('typeRapport');
}
```